# Script does not show the button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this code:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_gui()
    def init_gui(self):
        icon = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
        button = self.Button(0)
        button.set_icon(icon)
        button.init()

        self.show()

    class Button(QToolButton):
        def __init__(self, style):
            super().__init__()
            self.setToolButtonStyle(style)
            self.action = QAction()
        def set_icon(self, icon):
            self.action.setIcon(icon)
        def init(self):
            self.setDefaultAction(self.action)
```

Script runs, but it does not show the button.

I think, the button is not child to ### Window object ### parent.

Answer (score 0):

Place button in layout

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        lay = QGridLayout(self)            # <---

        icon = QIcon("im.png")
        button = Button(0)
        button.set_icon(icon)
        button.init()
        lay.addWidget(button)              # <---


class Button(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, style):
        super().__init__()
        self.setToolButtonStyle(style)
        self.action = QAction()

    def set_icon(self, icon):
        self.action.setIcon(icon)

    def init(self):
        self.setDefaultAction(self.action)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me it? Why the layout fixed it?

Comment: @JohnDoe   Layout management in PyQt5  http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/